# Private/Public Key Windows

Tags: python, ssh-keys

How to create a trusted communication from two nodes windows?(no windows server)
I know the procedure on Linux:

1. - generate ssh keys
2. - upload in another node the public key and place in authorized_keys

I need use this procedure on windows using python code.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at how ansible is achieving this by using the [pywinrm](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm), some details [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html).
Also worth mentioning that the latest(s) version of Windows 10 add ssh server and client optional features, depending on your use-case it might be enough or not.